# Python get a value in JSON array

Tags: arrays, json, python-3.x

In Python 3-x, consider you have an array in JSON syntax:

```
members = '''[
    {
        "name" : "Amber",
        "age"  : 5 
    },
    {
        "name" : "Becky",
        "age"  : 4 
    }
]'''
```

How do you get the value for `age` where the `name` is `Amber`? (The answer should be `5`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

variable members look like a string so first change string to json object and search what you want.

```
members = '''[
        {
            "name" : "Amber",
            "age"  : 5 
        },
        {
            "name" : "Becky",
            "age"  : 4 
        }
    ]'''
    import json
    obj = json.loads(members) #Changing string to json
    for some_variable in obj:
        if some_variable['name'] == 'Amber':
            print (some_variable['age']) # will print 5
```

Comment: `all` is not a good word to use for a variable since it is a reserved keyword in python. Also you should `break` out of the loop after you got what you wanted.

Comment: I just want to give a quick answer so I didn't pay no attendion.Yes all is reserved word your are right .Thanks to remembered me :) @Error-SyntacticalRemorse